# How to determine which size of auger to get for backed up basement floor drain?

Tags: water, basement, drain, drainage, back-up

My basement floor drain is backing up water (~10L) when washer is dispensing water during the spin cycle. It's an older house at 1955. The drain looks like it has a p-trap.

I wonder how can I determine which power auger tool to rent from HomeDepot with respect to 1) the diameter of the auger cable, 2) length of the cable, and 3) size and type of tips, do I simply measure the diameter of the drain pipe?

Comment: Is it a 2,3,4" drain? Is there a clean out that would provide a straight shot. Going through a p trap will require a smaller snake. But if you have a straight shot a larger one will clean more than a small one. Last is this city or septic trees on the main possibly causing the trouble? This would require a cutting head usually avabial on larger machines.

Comment: How can I determine if it's 2, 3, or 4" drain? Is it referring to the diameter of the drain opening?

Comment: Going in at a p trap probably 1-1/2" this would limit the snake to 1/4". Going in through a clean out usually 3 or 4" a 7/8 could be used I don't remember any snakes larger than 7/8 .

Comment: There is a stand pipe the water from washer goes into that is connected to the floor drain under the ground. Can I snake there to clear the clog in the floor drain?

Comment: The stand pipe will have a trap but a 1/4" should make it through. Keep spinning as it gets hard in the trap with light pressure it should go through. For main line plugs I try to find a clean out or go through a roof vent with a larger machine to fully clear I am guessing you have 4" cast main line with oakum and lead seals this was common in the 50's tree and shrub roots get in and cause stuff to collect until it starts backing up. A root cutting head on a larger snake may be needed or you will be doing it again in a month. I had 1 house that I had to do every year until I replaced the pipe.

Comment: I just did some measure of the floor drain. It has a p-trap and the diameter of the opening before the p trap is around 3.5 inch. Do you the size of auger and tips I should get?